# iPhone subview w/ transparent background and clickthrough behavior

Tags: iphone, xcode, interface-builder

I have an application with several views and a tab controller.

I've created a view that contains the elements for the header of my application which is consistent on every view. This way I do not need to recreate the header on every view, I can just overlay the HeaderView over the tabbarcontroller.

The problem is that when I add the new HeaderView as a subview to my tabbarcontroller, it makes the entire app appear white because the subview is taking over the entire screen rather than just drawing the elements inside of the view.

I made the background of my HeaderView 0% opaque, which allows me to see the elements behind my HeaderView, but I cannot interact with any of them.

One solution might be to size the HeaderView to show only the elements I need, but unfortunately the header has variable sizes because sometimes a dialog or tableview might become active.

I'm looking to make the HeaderView the topmost view in my application, but I want it to ignore the view background and only draw the visible elements of my HeaderView.

Let me know if you need any clarification!

Thanks,
Dave